# How to change the CSS of particular tag inside of iframe using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a product where my requirement is when user focus on particular text box then change the background color of particular tag using the class of that tag inside iFrame. I have tried few solutions from stack but got no luck.
Here is my code
Below is Html code.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control bodyStyle" name="bodyFontSizeDesk" id="bodyFontSizeDesk" value="" placeholder="px">
```

Below is my js code.

```
$('.bodyStyle').on('focus', function() {
$('iframe').contents().find(".headings").css('background', 'red');
```

});

Below is the tag inside iframe.

```
<h1 class="headings">Street artist & painter based in New Delhi.</h1>
```

Any lead will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the iframe content from the same server/origin as the page it is in?

Comment: yes both are on same server

Comment: Do you have the rights to access the iframe?

Comment: yes i can access

Comment: If on the same server, why use iFrame at all? Ajax the page into a div on the parent page

Comment: iFrame is required because of some requirements.

Comment: Works for me with the code given. https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7xnc0y35/ Any console errors?

Comment: this is the iFrame src can you do same on this source https://prajesh-wakade.udee.space/

Comment: this code doesn't work on this source